# Showing plotly on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I have a dataframe 'country' that I am plotting using jupyter notebook.

It plotted nicely on Kaggle's notebook, but refuses to show when I use jupyter notebook..

I've read similar problems on StackOverflow, and I've tried both :

```
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

&

```
py.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

Please find the full code below:

```
import plotly.offline as py
from plotly.offline import iplot
py.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Bar(
    x= country.index,
    y= country['Avg. Points'],
    name='Avg. Points'
)

trace2= go.Bar(
    x= country.index,
    y= country['Avg. Price'],
    name='Avg. Price'
)

data=[trace1, trace2]
layout=go.Layout(
    barmode='stack')

fig=go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='stacked-bar')
```

The below image is how it looks on Kaggle.[image]

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried using your code, replacing your data with some of Plotly's [example](https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/) data. I'm not able to replicate the issue you're having. Assuming you have correctly installed plotly using `$ pip install plotly` and there are no issues with the data, the following should work.

`from plotly.offline import iplot` isn't necessary, since you use `py.iplot`.

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

trace1 = go.Bar(
    x= country.index,
    y= country['Avg. Points'],
    name='Avg. Points'
)

trace2= go.Bar(
    x= country.index,
    y= country['Avg. Price'],
    name='Avg. Price'
)

data=[trace1, trace2]
layout=go.Layout(barmode='stack')

fig=go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='stacked-bar')
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I had a Jupyter notebook with plotly images that loaded in past using the fig.show() command. However, this is no longer working reproducibly and was able to fix the issue with two statements from above: import plotly.offline as py
and py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

Comment: Glad it helped!